# Why Visual Studio 2019 is not creating Content, AppData, Scripts folder

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019

I have installed `Visual Studio 2019 community edition.` When I am creating a .NET Core MVC project, Visual Studio is not creating the desired folders structure.

I have followed the Visual Studio 2019 wizard to create an MVC project. One other problem I am facing is that .NET 2.2 is not available while the selection of the environment, So I am using 2.1 here. Please help.

My Folder Structure contains:

Connected Services

Dependencies,

Properties,

wwwroot,

CONTROLLERS (Folder),

MODEL (Folder),

VIEWS (Folder),

appsettings,

Program.cs,

Startup.cs

Comment: That is how the .Net Core MVC project is supposed to create your folder structure.  The folders you expect are from an older project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is the new `asp core mvc` structure.all you need to do is to place your static files in `wwwroot` folder, use `startup.cs` instead of the old app-start and maybe the appsettings for your application settings.

Comment: And where are "my" static files? Are we supposed to have something pre-cooked before 
creating a new project? It seems to me like a step backwards compared to the old framework.

Answer (score 0):

Asp Core Mvc does not create those directories.

Asp Core Mvc directories structure:

> - Application files
> - Configuration files
> - Static assets
> - Packages
> - A runtime (self-contained deployment only)

You can read and learn more about that here : [ASP.NET Core directory structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/directory-structure?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

[ASP.NET Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#pivot=core)